# Esrog: How do you tell if a scratch or mark on the top half is a problem?

Tags: sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Esrog: How do you tell if a small scratch, nick, or mark on the top half (near the pitum) is a problem? If it's not mehudar, or חסר? What are the practical guidelines?
People often bring such cases to a Rav for examination, but I wonder what the Rav does exactly.

Comment: There are two parts to this: knowing the halachot and knowing how to spot certain things. The latter at least is surely only learned through experience checking

Comment: A good starting point would be, as Double AA wrote above, to know the halachos. A good point for start reading is in the Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim, siman 648 (:7 for example).

Comment: @Shmuel I have seen the halachos. I'm asking about the part with the experience. Is the answer that it can't really be answered with words?

Comment: Unfortunately with that I cannot help. I have no experience in that field unfortunately.